# Omit one of double dative case using "und" sentence connection

Tags: dative, redundancy

I am unsure if this is correct German:

> ... bei der die einfache Verknüpfung von und die Interaktion mit Entitäten gewährleistet ist.

Here "Entitäten" is the dative case and I omitted it just before the "und":

> ... bei der die einfache Verknüpfung von [Entitäten] und die Interaktion mit Entitäten gewährleistet ist.

I think it should be correct but maybe there should be some punctuation mark or something?

Is there a special name for this construct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fully correct. The punctuation is correct as well. Carlster has given an alternative. Which one to use is a question of style.

This construct is called [*zusammengezogener Satz*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Ordnung/Zusammenziehung.html).

Answer (score 5):

When speaking, you can stress "von" and "mit" (and add a little break after "von"), so people will understand. Written down, it's a little hard to grasp (but still correct).

Even after adding a comma the sentence remains bumpy:

> ...bei der die einfache Verknüpfung von, und die Interaktion mit Entitäten gewährleistet ist.

Maybe:

> ...bei der sowohl die einfache Verknüpfung von Entitäten, als auch die Interaktion mit ihnen gewährleistet ist.

---

Alternatives

Turn it around:

> ...bei der sowohl die Interaktion mit Entitäten, als auch die einfache Verknüpfung dieser gewährleistet ist.

Allow repetition:

> ...bei der die einfache Verknüpfung von Entitäten und auch die Interaktion mit Entitäten gewährleistet ist.

Comment: The first alternative does not need (allow?) the comma. The second, remove both "die", imho, but that one is ... bumpy.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct; some hints for style:

- I'd remove both "die"; keep it general.
- Replacing "und" with "sowie" can make this sentence sound a bit smoother.
- Adding an appropriate attribute to "Entitäten" can be nice, e.g. "beliebigen" (whatever fits in your context).

For instance:

> ... bei der einfache Verknüpfung von sowie Interaktion mit beliebigen Entitäten gewährleistet ist.

Depending on the context, it may be nicer still to get rid of the nouns. You talk about activites so using verbs is more natural:

> ... bei der gewährleistet ist, dass Entitäten einfach verknüpft werden können und man mit ihnen interagieren kann.

The "man" is a little crutch; you are mixing two subjects (*Entitäten* werden verknüpft, aber *jmd.* interagiert mit ihnen). I'd probably rewrite more than just this part of the sentence in order to get rid of this.